# Split keyboard with duplicated keys

Tags: keyboards, ergonomics

Does there exist an ergonomic split keyboard, like this:

[image: Split keyboard]

But where the keys don't stop at the 'official' typing boundary. Sometimes I want to type a B with my right hand, and these kinds of keyboards make it infuriating.

Note that Apple realised split keyboards should have duplicated keys - the [iPad split keyboard has (invisible) duplicates](http://www.mactrast.com/2012/02/the-ipads-split-keyboard-has-6-hidden-keys-to-improve-your-typing/):

Are there any physical keyboards that do the same thing, or at *least* duplicate the B (it's exactly in the middle on many keyboards and Apple even put it on the right side of their split keyboard)?

[image: iPad keyboard]

Comment: I'm not sure there is such a keyboard (assuming you don't go out of your way to get one custom made). The reason being that you are [supposed to use a certain finger to press a certain key.](http://spaceplace.nasa.gov/review/sign-here-typing/keyboard.en.jpg)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So, there is no keyboards with a dedicated "B" key on both sides so I found the next best thing.

[The Ergo Pro](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00ZWPR506) is fully separated, and has some good reviews. but what it has that you really need, an extra key to the left of the N key, on the right side. The reason this is important is because you can easily remap that key to send in a b.

[Map Any Key to Any Key on Windows 10, 8, 7, or Vista](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/map-any-key-to-any-key-on-windows-xp-vista/) - This article gives you a little write up about how this can be done and even gives a software rec that looks extremely basic. I haven't looked, but I'm certain there are Mac key remapping programs as well.

I originally found this keyboard [In this article](http://thewirecutter.com/reviews/comfortable-ergo-keyboard/). It was determined to be one of the best split key keyboards around.

[Here is the companies website, they have it listed for $200](http://matias.ca/ergopro/pc/)

Answer (score 2):

I have a [keychron Q10](https://www.keychron.com/pages/keychron-q10-customizable-mechanical-keyboard), shown here, and like all "Alice style" keyboards from keychron, it has a duplicate B key.

[image: Duplicate B keys]